# Tizen Wearable Update Mode

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, wearables

I wanted to test out how does my app handles update so I checked checkbox 'Update Mode' in Run Configuration window.

Then while uploading I got

> Unknown Error [90]

I tried restarting watch thinking there could be some background service running in my app (which I have) but I still get the same error. Disabling Update Mode worked - but the app has been removed and with this all of data stored in database.

Do you know what could be the reason? I tried it a while ago and it used to work. Couldn't find any useful information about code either. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have seen something along those lines, but need to make sure if the same issue is described or not: I am working with Tizen based displays, not wearables. Also we are developing a web application on Tizen, not a native one. Still, since the web app also uses the native functions via interfaces provided, it may be the same issue. Sometimes when downloading files I encounter the error `Unknown Error [?]` where the question mark is 90 iirc. Will write it down next time I see it. We noticed it is related to downloads, but are not sure what the cause is.

Comment: @KVNSTOBJEKT good catch, haven't thought about that. Gonna do more testing

Answer (score 0):

If 'Update Mode' worked properly before and now it's throwing unknown error constantly, In that case this could be a Tizen-Studio Bug.

You may report a bug on [Tizen bug Tracker](https://bugs.tizen.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa). Here’s a guideline on [how to report bugs](https://www.tizen.org/community/bug-tracker/how-report-bugs?langswitch=en&langredirect=1).  Share your progress and the 'Reported bug' link here to help other developers in this forum keep track.

You can find the Previous IDE versions here:

https://download.tizen.org/sdk/Installer/

Download Previous Tizen-Studio versions and try 'Update Mode'.